# What does @format mean in new react native App.js?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I started to create an Application in `react native` so, i setup the `react native` environment and found the `@format` in the `App.js` file when i open this file first time. Please can anyone tell what is `@format` and why it is in the new `App.js` file in `react native`?

Answer (score 24):

Refer to the @Noitidart's link in comment, the @format is part of pragma and another pragma is @prettier. Prettier will only format those files with pragma when option of **Require pragma** is enabled. Thanks @Noitidart for the link.

---

I found this after I check the blame of App.js file in react native repo.

[Prettier RN local-cli](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/aba4ec0c0984caf3bec75a803080bd95722b35db)

And I found this description in RN 0.48.4 features
[Enforce Prettier for @format (1023070) - @TheSavior](https://libupdate.com/libs/28d548bc-7320-4f0e-98a9-ca94de08fe7e)

As conclusion, the @format tag is used to tell the prettier tool to run on that file and so that it's format becomes prettier.

Comment: This is the correct answer. See prettier config "Require pragma" for more info - https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#require-pragma

Answer (score 0):

The demo code created with `npx react-native init YourNameProject` (found in this [guide](https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup)) generates this annotation.

The Prettier's [documentation](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#require-pragma) says the annotation `@format` is related to Pragma.

> Prettier can restrict itself to only format files that contain a special comment, called a pragma, at the top of the file. This is very useful when gradually transitioning large, unformatted codebases to Prettier.

> Prettier can insert a special @format marker at the top of files specifying that the file has been formatted with Prettier.

Answer (score -8):

> Its called **decorators**. It’s just a function that takes as an argument what it decorates:

@myFunction

class MyClass { }

**is equivalent to:**

class MyClass { }

myFunction(MyClass)

Using decorators allows us to extend a function (class or property) by wrapping a function (decorator) around it. This can be useful for making properties read-only or suppressing warnings from a function.

**reference :**
https://moduscreate.com/blog/using-es2016-decorators-in-react-native/

Comment: So, you mean that in the case of `@format` the `format` is function that takes all the content in the `App.js` file as an argument ?

Comment: Format is higher order component which takes class as an argument. You will find most probably a file from which format is imported and App is your class. For more detail about HOC just read the link: https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html

Comment: This is obviously, demonstrably wrong. Anyone reading this, move on from this answer.

Comment: It is not the decorator see prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#require-pragma